# How to give a distinctive colour to each variable in matplotlib and pandas?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am creating a times series graph with matplot. The outcome of the function I'm using gives me:

```
plt.figure(); data_actuals_month.plot(figsize=(10, 7)); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

the problem is that many variables get the same colour making it impossible to interpret the graph.

How to change the colour scheme and give to each variable its own colour? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the color used before plotting by giving a list of colors to `matplotlib.plot` :

```
 matplotlib.plot.rc('axes', color_cycle=['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'])
```

Or to `ax` :

```
 ax1.set_color_cycle(['c', 'm', 'y', 'k'])
```

See : http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html

I don't know how pandas uses matplotlib, but I see no reason this shouldn't work. You might also want to try to use different dashstyle/marker/linewidth (http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/index.html), although I'm not sure there is an equivalent of `color_cycle` for those.